# O efeito Scrolling Nav não funciona no Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

O efeito `Scrolling Nav`do meu [site](http://www.acmanaus.com.br) não está funcionando no Google Chrome, porem no Firefox, Edge, Safari e etc, está funcionando normal, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Isto ocorreu devido a uma mudança no Chrome 61, conforme o [Blog (15 Agosto 2017)](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/08/chrome-61-beta-javascript-modules.html):

> To align with the spec and preserve browser consistency, the scrollingElement is now the documentElement in standards mode.
>
> ---
>
> Detalhes sobre o *standards mode*: https://dev.opera.com/articles/fixing-the-scrolltop-bug/
>
> **Nota:** Encontrei a informação graças a uma postagem em [**AutoScroll on chat exchange doesn't work in chrome 61**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300552/198279)

Uma possível maneira de corrigir é mudar o elemento que receberá o scroll para isto:

```
var el = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
```

Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement

> **Nota:** se estiver usando jQuery atualize ele pra versão mais recente, provavelmente já corrigiram o bug nele.